# custom angular filter gives TypeError cannot call undefined, but variable is defined and works

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made the following Angular filter to make a word all uppercase:

```
   angular.module('module.name').filter('toUpperCase', function() {
        return function(input) {
            return input.toUpperCase();
        };
   });
```

In my views I'm using the following line:

```
   {{city | toUpperCase}}
```

When I'm running the code city gets converted to upper cases as it should. However when I look in my console I get the following error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot call method 'toUpperCase' of undefined
```

I get this error two times for every filter I use. Should every filter you make first check if there is any input before executing code or something?

Comment: At first run `city` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This error is going to be thrown when JavaScript tries to access any property of an undefined object.

You can use the **default-hack** pattern to suppress this:

```
return function(input) {
  input = input || '';
  return input.toUpperCase();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a check in your filter function that checks to make sure the the input it receives is a valid string before calling `toUpperCase()` on it.

```
angular.module('module.name').filter('toUpperCase', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return input && input.toUpperCase ? input.toUpperCase() : input;
    };
});
```

As angular updates the bindings to `city`, you can get a moment where `city` is undefined or null, but still goes through the filter.  Using the code above, you are making sure that you only try to uppercase something if it is a valid argument.

That being said, just so you know, there is already an `uppercase` filter built into angular.  The docs for that are found [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3auppercase)